# LibGDX HTML runs slowly

Tags: performance, gwt, libgdx

I've been writing a game with LibGDX and it's been running smoothly on both desktop and Android for months now, although I recently tried to deploy it to HTML. Unfortunately, it runs at <1 fps in Chrome. Even when I take out some effects, it's very slow. I get about 5fps with ~5 images on the screen and 320x240 resolution.

I just installed GWT for this and am not familiar with web stuff, so I'm probably missing something crucial. I compile and run, select "Web Application", then click on the link Eclipse gives me in the "Development Mode" panel. I get a cool loading bar, and then my game shows up and plays like it's on the ENIAC. What steps do I take to make this run normally? Sorry if this is vague, this is my first web game so I don't know what I don't know, and the Google was coming up dry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are running it in "hosted" mode, with the debugger attached. This is generally the case when running from Eclipse by choosing "Debug as Web Application" or "Run as Web Application". Unfortunately, this makes it incredibly slow. If you detach the debugger (by removing the query string from the launch url), the speed will increase substantially. Also, you might try [Super Dev](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3073) mode.

Note that doing a full GWT Compile of the project and running it from an external web server will also run at full speed.

Comment: Where is this query string and/or launch url and how do I do that? I see a URL "http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997" which takes me to my game.

Comment: That is the launch url. The query string starts at the question mark, so remove everything beginning with the question mark.

Comment: I get an error from Chrome if I do that: GWT module "com.xx.xx.GWTDefinition" definition may need to be (re)compiled."

Comment: I've done that? I've built, cleaned, rebuilt, and I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Try doing an actual compile: Right-click the project -> Google -> GWT Compile

Comment: Yes I have done that. I get a tremendous output in Eclipse that ends telling me 6 permutations have been compiled. I have no projectname.html in my war folder like Google says I will, but an index.html, which doesn't do anything. Thank you for all this help so far.

Comment: The only other thing I'd suggest is to try deleting the gwt-unitCache folder within the gwt project and see if that helps. If that doesn't do it, we should probably take this to the "chat" area.

Comment: I think this bug is suited for another question. Thanks for your help. I tested this in a fresh project without the error and it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the web games by libGDX run slow on the local server(Reason may be the same as @nEx.Software told) but when you upload your game on the global server, it will run smoothly.You can try if you can.